# Get rooms visibility in Outlook using Java

Tags: java, exchangewebservices, outlook-restapi

I'm trying to devise an interviewing module using Java. I am using the EWS APIs and successfully able to get the free / busy calendars.

However, I am facing a problem while trying to get the list of meeting / conference rooms. I tried using the `getRoomLists` method, but that returned an empty list. Is there any other way to get the room availability using the EWS API / some other mechanisms?

Or can someone guide me how to use the `getRoomLists` correctly?

This is what I am currently trying:

```
ExchangeService exservice ;

EmailAddressCollection listOfRooms = exservice.getRoomLists();
```

Comment: Hi, I did't find any error, I'm getting empty List.

Answer (score 0):

Getting an empty list when calling `GetRoomLists` usually means that no room lists have been configured on the Exchange Server.

See here: [Get room lists by using EWS in Exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-get-room-lists-by-using-ews-in-exchange)

> Room lists don't exist by default; your administrator needs to create
>   and organize them.